# Get all the records from API that limits page size but have multiple pages

Tags: php

I am using PHP and curl to call an API to get records. The API I am calling has a limit of 100 records at a time, but provides a page_number parameter so you can select the next page. How do I get the total number of all the records from every page?

So for example the API url will look something like this:

```
$url = "https://api.shop.com/v1/products?page_size=100&page_number=(what to put here to get all the pages?)";
```

The API does not provide such info. It's different for every account and so there is no way for me to even find out how many products there are. I want to know if I can put a range in the page_number parameter.

Comment: Doesn't the API provide that info? A "good" API would have total entries, last page, from, to etc in its response

Comment: `?page_size=100&page_number=(what to put here to get all the pages?)` - you obviously can not put a single value here and make one single request, when the API has a limit on the maximum number of records it will return in one request. If your first request return a 100 records, then you need to increase your page number by one, and make the next request ... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the API has another method for this, you will probably need to do this iteratively until you reach a page that has fewer items than requested.

So, for example:

```
<?php

$page_size = 100;
$total_found = 0;

while true {
    // Make API request
    // I assume you end up with an array of results that you can count
    $records_found = count($results)
    $total_found += $records_found;
    if ($records_found < $page_size) {
        // If you asked for 100 records, but got less than 100, then
        // naturally, you must be on the last page, so we're done.
        break; // Exit the loop
    }
}

// Now you have a variable $total_found with the sum of all the
// records you found. You can do whatever you want with it, like print it.
echo $total_found.PHP_EOL;
```